# What is the best way to kill a banana shoot but not the entire plant?

Tags: growth, banana

Well the recent winter was pretty bad for the bananas, so I cut them down to ground level, and new shoots are coming up. Great (although that means no flowers or bananas this year).

The problem now is that I have a shoot coming up in the lawn! I can easily cut that back, but it will keep growing. Banana 'trunks' are just leaves wrapped around each other. Even if I cut the shoot, the inner leaf will keep growing. So how can I kill this one shoot but not kill the entire plant/clump?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't very easily - I'd dig around the base of the actual plant and isolate the root/shoot that goes into the lawn and cut that off below ground, together with any others which are straying where you don't want them too.

Comment: Thanks - I'm going to try that this weekend. I may have to lift a border, though!